# Angular Route Metadata in Guards

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, guard

Back in angularjs (using ui-router). You could add metadata to your routes and use those in routechanges.

In angular there are Guards for this, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the metadata out of the route definition.

To give you a more concrete example, I would like to be able to add metadata to a route, let's say required roles and or permissions and have a guard do the heavy lifting.

Route definitions:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '',
        component: MyComponent,
        data: {
            permissions: ["view"],
            roles: ["admin", "user"]
        }
    },
    ...
]);
```

And then in my Guard:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    //How to get a hold of the data defined for the current route ?
    console.log(route.data); //returns an empty object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`route.data[ 'permissions' ][ 0 ]` should be the string `view` in the `canActivate` method of `MyGuard`. `MyGuard` should implement `CanActivate`. Your routing should look like this:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    data: {
        permissions: ["view"],
        roles: ["admin", "user"]
    },
    canActivate: [ MyGuard ]
}
```

And this routing should work when accessing the root of the route. [A detailed explanation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) can be found on the official angular site.

Comment: I indeed realised later on that my guard was on the wrong route definition. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

On Angular 15 you can do this with `ActivatedRoute.data`. Start by declaring the data in your route config:

##### app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "", data: {someItem: "someValue"}, title: "home", component: HomeComponent
}, {
  path: "somePath", data: {someItem: "someOtherValue"}, title:"sometitle", component: SomeComponent
}];
```

#### your.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(() => {
    route.children[0].data.subscribe(data => console.log(data["someItem"]));
    });
  }
}
```